# c synchronise write to stdout and stderr

Tags: c, unix, synchronization, ls, unistd.h

I am implementing ls program. Everything is working properly, besides synchronisation of error messages and normal output.
I store information in big buffers (200kb). 
As you can see subfolder2 has no rights to be opened. 
My program works recursively and opens folder tests, then reads all of it's content, than writes it to stdout. Then it opens folder, displays all content. Same with subfolder1. When it meets subfolder 2, it gets errno and writes explanation in stderr. It works in debugger and doesn't work in reality, because it places output where it wants, not at the end. 
And it  works perfectly it when  uses stdout, like on the example in the bottom.

```
/Users/qhetting/ft_ls/tests
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 qhetting 2018 102 Mar 30 14:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 qhetting 2018 646 Mar 30 15:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 qhetting 2018 136 Mar 30 14:10 folder

/Users/qhetting/ft_ls/tests/folder
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 4 qhetting 2018 136 Mar 30 14:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 qhetting 2018 102 Mar 30 14:08 ..
drwxrwxrwx 2 qhetting 2018  68 Mar 30 14:09 subfolder1
d--------- 2 qhetting 2018  68 Mar 30 14:10 subfolder2

/Users/qhetting/ft_ls/tests/folder/subfolder1
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 qhetting 2018  68 Mar 30 14:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 qhetting 2018 136 Mar 30 14:10 ..

ft_ls: subfolder2: Permission denied
```

Code:

```
 if (!(dir = opendir(fld_name)))
            {
                if (errno)
                    print_error(fld_name, errno, NULL); //gets file name, concatenates it with error message and prints it with write like
write(2, error, strlen(error));
                return;
            }
            errno = 0;
            while ((dirp = readdir(dir)))
            {
                if (!(g_flag & A && dirp->d_name[0] != '.') || g_flag & A)
                {
                    attrib = ft_relink(attrib, dirp->d_name,
                                       get_full_path(fld_name, dirp->d_name));
                    if (first_asign)
                    {
                        holder = attrib;
                        first_asign = false;
                    }
                }
                if (errno)
                {
                    print_error(fld_name, errno, attrib);
                    errno = 0;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            attrib = holder;
            ft_merge_sort(&attrib, comparator_lex);
            print_level(attrib, g_flag); //here all read content is printed in stdout with big buffer.
            if (g_flag & R_BIG)
            {
                while (attrib)
                {
                    if (IS_OK && is_dir(attrib->full_path) && !attrib->error_message)
                        ft_open_folder(attrib->full_path);
                    attrib = attrib->next;
                }
            }
            closedir(dir);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fflush(stdout)` and `fflush(stderr)` to flush the output buffers. Doing so will print whatever is left in the buffer immediately.

> **Synopsis**
>
> `int fflush(FILE *stream);`
>
> **Description**
>
> If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

[https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.2)

Comment: What to do if it doesn't help?